# Creating a Multi-dimensional Array Based on Known Keys Only

Tags: php

I am attempting to convert a string into a multi-dimensional array with keys that are only allowed.

Given the string:

`"type:blue, type:red, shift:second, shift:first, category:circle, system:unknown"`

With the only possible keys:

```
$possibleKeys = [ "category", "shift", "type" ];
```

Create the array:

```
$searchArray = array( "type"  => [ "blue", "red" ],
                      "shift" => [ "second", "first" ],
                      "category" => [ "circle" ]
                     );
```

So `system:unknown` is not added to the `$searchArray` as it is not in the `$possibleKeys` array.

Here is my code:

```
$myString = "type:blue, type:red, shift:second, shift:first, category:circle, system:unknown";

$params = explode( ",", $myString );
$possibleKeys = [ "category", "shift", "type", "chances" ];

$nodes = [];
foreach ($params as $param) {
    $node = explode( ":", $param );

    if (array_key_exists( $node[ 0 ], $nodes ) && in_array( $node[ 0 ], $possibleKeys )) {
        array_push( $nodes[ $node[ 0 ] ], $node[ 1 ] );
    } else {
        $nodes[ $node[ 0 ] ] = $node[ 1 ];
    }
}
```

But when I `var_dump` the array is garbage and some keys have extra spaces.

```
array(4) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(9) "blue"
  [" type"]=>
  string(8) "red"
  [" shift"]=>
  string(5) "first"
  [" category"]=>
  string(3) "circle"
}
```

***What am I doing wrong?***

Comment: Correct. It is not added to the array.

Comment: Got it. Sorry, didn't notice you have added that info. Got a solution. Posting it as an answer.

Comment: Apply `trim()`.

Comment: I'll take another half an hour. Travelling. `:(`

Comment: I must say it's a very well formulated question. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First build your associative array with your allowed keys.

Break your string up - first `explode` into an array by comma delimiter to get your pairs, then `trim` and `explode` each pair.  If the left side is an allowed key, add the right side to the associative array element.  As usual more than one way to do it, but this is what my current caffeine levels call for...

```
<?php
$dataString="type:blue, type:red, shift:second, shift:first, category:circle, system:unknown";

$desiredResult=array();
foreach(array("category", "shift", "type") as $desiredKey){
    $desiredResult[$desiredKey]=array();
}

$tmpArr=explode(",",$dataString);

foreach($tmpArr as $pair){
    $pair=trim($pair);
    $pairArr=explode(":",$pair);
    if(isset($desiredResult[$pairArr[0]])){
        $desiredResult[$pairArr[0]][]=$pairArr[1];
    }
}

print_r($desiredResult);

?>
```

Gives

```
Array
(
    [category] => Array
        (
            [0] => circle
        )

    [shift] => Array
        (
            [0] => second
            [1] => first
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => blue
            [1] => red
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to find the values and loop only the possible keys.
This means it only does three iterations to find all values and put them in the array.
The preg_match will find all words connected to the key in the full string.

```
$myString = "type:blue, type:red, shift:second, shift:first, category:circle, system:unknown";
$possibleKeys = [ "category", "shift", "type" ];

foreach($possibleKeys as $key){
    preg_match_all("/" . $key . ":(.*?),/", $myString, $m);
    $new[$key] = $m[1]; // $m[1] will hold all the matching values to the key searched for
}
var_dump($new);
```

The output is:

```
array(3) {
  ["category"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "circle"
  }
  ["shift"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "second"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "first"
  }
  ["type"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "blue"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "red"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/XAeRC

Comment: I like this solution as it does not require me to have an additional array of ignored keys.

Comment: @user-44651 in all fairness I believe ivanivans answer don't need it either

Answer (score 0):

Because you explode with "," try to explode with ", " (comma space) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do small tweaks with your code and avoid some extra method using like `trim()` or `array_key_exits()`

```
<?php
$myString = "type:blue, type:red, shift:second, shift:first, category:circle, system:unknown";

$params = explode( ", ", $myString ); // explode by comma & space with
$possibleKeys = [ "category", "shift", "type", "chances" ];
$ignore = ['system'];

$nodes = [];
foreach ($params as $param) {
    $node = explode( ":", $param );
    if (in_array( $node[0], $possibleKeys )) {
        $nodes[$node[0]][] = $node[1];
    } else {
        $nodes[$node[0]] = $node[1];
    }
}

foreach($ignore as $key) {
   unset($nodes[$key]);
}

print '<pre>';
print_r($nodes);
print '</pre>';
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/Udav9

Comment: This answer means you have to manually add items to the ignore array if any new unwanted is added to the string